# unable to delete data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project on codeigniter. I want to delete the data from database. if user clicks a delete button it should be deleted.

**my problem**
I think all code is working ..but I think **id is not getting** in my `controller`
there is no error, but data is also not deleting from database

**offerfetch.php**(view)

```
<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="<?= base_url('admin/delarticles'); ?>/<?php echo $emp->offer_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>

<td><a type="button"  class="btn btn-info" href="<?= base_url('admin/editoffer'); ?>/<?php echo $emp->offer_id; ?>">update</a></td>
```

**admin.php**(controller)

```
  public function delarticles()
  {
    $id=$this->input->get('offer_id');
     $this->load->model('adminloginmodel');
       if($this->adminloginmodel->del($id))
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('insertsuccess','Delete Successfully');
           $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class','alert-success');
       }
       else
       {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('insertsuccess','Please try again..not delete');
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class','alert-danger');
       }
       return redirect('admin/viewoffers');
 
  }
```

**in order to debug**
I have used

```
print_r($id);
exit();
```

after the line `$id=$this->input->get('offer_id');` in a controller but I'm not getting any id, blank page is coming up.

**adminloginmodel.php**(model)

```
    public function del($id)
  {
      
    return $this->db->delete('offers',['offer_id'=>$id]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the id through the url of your anchor element:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="<?= base_url('admin/delarticles'); ?>/<?php echo $emp->offer_id; ?>">Delete</a>
```

which should generate something like:

```
href="your_app/admin/delarticles/1"
```

you are trying to read the id as it was coming from an input field from a form, that's not the case here, you can access it directly in your function from url like

```
public function delarticles($id=0){
    if ($id){
        $this->load->model('adminloginmodel');
        if($this->adminloginmodel->del($id))
        {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('insertsuccess','Delete Successfully');
           $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class','alert-success');
        }
        else
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('insertsuccess','Please try again..not delete');
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class','alert-danger');
        }
        return redirect('admin/viewoffers');
    }else{
       // your code in case there is no value for $id, aka $id=0
    }
}
```

Resuming:

1. if you use a form and a submit button within this form, you create a $_POST array from your form's input fields (e.g. `<input type="text" name="offer_id">` , which you can read in the controller with `$id=$this->input->get('offer_id')`;
2. use an anchor element and send the parameter in the Url

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about two different ways of passing data do controllers. If you want to pass the ID as part of the URL, you should do it like [in the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods).
In this case, you'd solve it adding an argument to the controller method.

As seen:

**admin.php**

```php
  public function delarticles($id)
  {
     $this->load->model('adminloginmodel');
       if($this->adminloginmodel->del($id))
   ...
```